# mapdrives script use username and password

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use a VBScript to map network drives. The script is working just fine, except when I am trying to modified it in order to use different credentials (username and password).

```
Option Explicit
Dim WSHNetwork, strMsg, sUser, sPass

sUser = "user12"
sPass = "testpassword"

Set WSHNetwork = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Network")
Call Unmap
Call TryMapDrive("N", "\\192.168.0.10\Music")
Call TryMapDrive("M", "\\192.168.0.10\Movies")
Call TryMapDrive("P", "\\192.168.0.10\Pictures")
Call TryMapDrive("W", "\\192.168.0.10\Work")
Call TryMapDrive("S", "\\192.168.0.10\Store")

strMsg = ShowNetwork() + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + EnumNetworkDrives()
MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Network Properties"

Function TryMapDrive(cDrive, strShare, sUser, sPass)
  On Error Resume Next
  WSHNetwork.MapNetworkDrive cDrive & ":", strShare, sUser, sPass
  TryMapDrive = Err.Number = 0
End Function

Function ShowNetwork
  Dim strMsg

  strMsg = "UserName" & Chr(9) & "= " & WSHNetwork.UserName & vbCrLf & _
           "ComputerName" & Chr(9) & "= " & WSHNetwork.ComputerName 
  ShowNetwork = strMsg
End Function

Function EnumNetworkDrives
  Dim colDrives, strMsg, i

  Set colDrives = WSHNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
  strMsg = "Current network drive connections: " & vbCrLf
  For i = 0 To colDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
    strMsg = strMsg & vbCRLF & colDrives(i) & Chr(9) & colDrives(i+1)
  Next
  EnumNetworkDrives = strMsg
End Function

Function Unmap
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim objNetwork, colDrives, i
  Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
  For i = 0 To colDrives.Count -1 Step 2
    objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive colDrives.Item(i)
  Next
End Function
```

When I am trying to start it with `sPass` and `sUser` it fails with the message below. Without trying different credentials, the script is working fine.

[image: Windows Script Host - error]

Comment: You are calling a function that requires 4 parameters but you are only passing two.

Comment: @ MC ND, thanks for the comment. I assume that I need to put these 2 parameters at the actual function calling lines? Unfortunately this had no effect - there is no error but it not mapping the drives actually.

Comment: *`not mapping the drives`* and, what the error (`Err.Number` or `Err.Description`) is?

Comment: `MapNetworkDrive(strLocalDrive, strRemoteShare, [persistent], [strUser], [strPassword])` while in different place, you are missing another parameter.

Comment: I am trying to understand it but unfortunately without success. For example: Call TryMapDrive("N", "\\192.168.0.10\Music", strUser, strPass) ?

Comment: Yes, the call to the `TryMapDrive` is correct that way, but the call to `WSHNetwork.MapNetworkDrive` is missing the `persistent` argument.

Comment: @MC ND HI, actually the issue was with the "Option Explicit" statement. After I removed it, everything is working fine, according your suggestions.Thank you!